# JS: submitting POST raw data (not KVP) into a new tab

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to submit raw data, in POST, to a new tab.

Something to the extent of:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.target = '_blank';
form.method = 'post';
form.action = 'https://example.com';

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'data'; // without this part*
input.value = 'some data';
form.appendChild(input);

form.submit();
```

only without the KVP format.
i.e. when calling `fopen('php://input', 'rb');` I want to get

```
'some data'
```

and not

```
'data="some data"'
```

Most importantly, I want to pass the data to a new tab and not get the response in AJAX

Comment: You would have to switch from a traditional form post to an ajax request to post application/json encoded data.

Comment: You can set the form's `enctype` property to `text/plain` which **will** populate PHP's `php://input` stream however you'll still need a named `<input>` which will send the data as `name=value`

Comment: @Phil - so from what you know, as well as from the hours I spent online, there's no way of doing that?